# CSS side menu - hidden sub menu controlled with radio input -- Can't seem to get it right

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues trying to implement CSS radio inputs to control the open/close function of the 3 Navigation items that have hidden sub-items. I had it working just fine using the hover state but decided to try a CSS radio or checkbox input.

I'm 2 months into learning css and html so I'm getting super frustrated with this! Below you'll see I have the radio inputs implement and functioning somewhat:

- Line 1 Nav Item - Opens all 3 drop down items ("line 1", "line 2", "line 3")
- Line 2 Nav Item - Closes "line 1" and opens "line 2" and "line 3"
- Line 3 Nav Item - Closes "line 1" and "line 2" and keeps "line 3" open

```css
aside {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*========== NAV ==========*/

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.2rem 0 1.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e1e1e1, #f5f5f5, #eaeaea);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: .4s;
}

.nav__container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* For mozilla */
}


/* For Google Chrome and others */

.nav__container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.nav__logo {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__list,
.nav__items {
  display: grid;
}

.nav__list {
  row-gap: 2.2rem;
}

.nav__items {
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.nav__subtitle {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: var(--text-color-light);
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #2180CF;
}

.nav__link:hover .nav__name {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: .7rem;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__logout {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}


/* Dropdown */

.nav__dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 21px;
  transition: all .1s ease-out .1s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__dropdown-collapse {
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.07);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem .75rem 1.8rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.nav__dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #2180CF;
}

.nav__dropdown-icon {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: .2s;
}


/* Show dropdown collapse */

input[type="radio"]:checked~*,
.nav__dropdown::before {
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}


/* Rotate icon arrow */

.radio:checked .nav__dropdown-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/*===== Show menu =====*/

.show-menu {
  left: 0;
}


/*===== Active link =====*/

.active {
  color: #2180CF;
}

.nav {
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.2rem 1rem 0 1.5rem;
  width: 72px;
  /* Reduced navbar */
}

.nav__items {
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 24px;
}


/* Element opacity */

.nav__logo-name,
.nav__name,
.nav__subtitle,
.nav__dropdown-icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .6s;
}


/* Navbar expanded */

.nav:hover {
  width: 230px;
}


/* Visible elements */

.nav:hover .nav__logo-name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__subtitle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__dropdown-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!--========== ICONS ==========-->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<aside>
  <!--========== NAV ==========-->
  <div class="nav" id="navbar">
    <nav class="nav__container">

      <div class="nav__items">
        <div class="nav__subtitle">PLANT #1</div>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown1" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown1" class="nav__name">Line 1</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 1</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 2</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 3</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 4</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown2" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown2" class="nav__name">Line 2</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
          <i class='bx bx-chart bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
          <span class="nav__name">OEE</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2 bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
          <span class="nav__name">Downtime</span>
        </a>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown3" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown3" class="nav__name">Line 3</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</aside>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for using Stack Snippets

Comment: I have no way of telling but I sense sarcasm. Did I not post the question correctly?

Comment: I'm saying, a lot of users only put a code block. Thanks for using Stack Snippets! (so we can now see the problem without pasting code into another program)

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to my CSS and I'm able to get it to function the way I want it to. Just not sure if it's the best approach.

```
.nav:hover #dropdown1:checked + .nav__dropdown {
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

.nav:hover #dropdown2:checked + .nav__dropdown{
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

.nav:hover #dropdown3:checked + .nav__dropdown{
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

/* Rotate icon arrow */
.nav:hover #dropdown1:checked + .nav__dropdown-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```css
aside {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*========== NAV ==========*/
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.2rem 0 1.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e1e1e1, #f5f5f5, #eaeaea);
  z-index: 100;
  transition: .4s;
}

.nav__container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-width: none; /* For mozilla */
}

/* For Google Chrome and others */
.nav__container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


.nav__logo {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__list,
.nav__items {
  display: grid;
}

.nav__list {
  row-gap: 2.2rem;
}

.nav__items {
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.nav__subtitle {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: var(--text-color-light);
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #2180CF;
}

.nav__link:hover .nav__name {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: .7rem;
}

 .nav__name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__logout {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

/* Dropdown */
.nav__dropdown{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 21px;
  transition: all .1s ease-out .1s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__dropdown-collapse {
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.07);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem .75rem 1.8rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.nav__dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #2180CF;

}

.nav__dropdown-icon {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: .2s;
}

/* Show dropdown collapse */
.nav:hover #dropdown1:checked + .nav__dropdown {
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

.nav:hover #dropdown2:checked + .nav__dropdown{
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

.nav:hover #dropdown3:checked + .nav__dropdown{
  max-height: 100rem;
  transition: all 1.7s ease-in .2s;
}

/* Rotate icon arrow */
.nav:hover #dropdown1:checked + .nav__dropdown-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
} 


/* Rotate icon arrow */
.radio:checked .nav__dropdown-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/*===== Show menu =====*/
.show-menu {
  left: 0;
}

/*===== Active link =====*/
.active {
  color: #2180CF;
}

.nav {
  left: 0;
  padding: 1.2rem 1rem 0 1.5rem;

  width: 72px; /* Reduced navbar */
}

.nav__items {
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* Element opacity */
.nav__logo-name,
.nav__name,
.nav__subtitle,
.nav__dropdown-icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .6s;
}


/* Navbar expanded */
.nav:hover {
  width: 230px;
}

/* Visible elements */
.nav:hover .nav__logo-name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__subtitle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav:hover .nav__dropdown-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!--========== ICONS ==========-->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<aside>
  <!--========== NAV ==========-->
  <div class="nav" id="navbar">
    <nav class="nav__container">

      <div class="nav__items">
        <div class="nav__subtitle">PLANT #1</div>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown1" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown1" class="nav__name">Line 1</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 1</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 2</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 3</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Example 4</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown2" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown2" class="nav__name">Line 2</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
          <i class='bx bx-chart bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
          <span class="nav__name">OEE</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2 bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
          <span class="nav__name">Downtime</span>
        </a>

        <input type="radio" id="dropdown3" name="dropdown">
        <div class="nav__dropdown">
          <a class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-buildings bx-tada-hover nav__icon'></i>
            <label for="dropdown3" class="nav__name">Line 3</label>
            <span class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon' </span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
            <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
              <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</aside>

</html>
```